# Adding a Highcharts 'Navigator' Component to Chart.js In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, chart.js

I'd like to add a box underneath my chart that users can drag in order to select the specific date range that they'd like to view. It's difficult to explain, but the Federal Reserve includes it with all their charts. Example here:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CAPB00004SQ

This is part of the charting library Highcharts, the relevant piece can be found here:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator

Basically, I want to have an area beneath a chart with three separate segments. Users can stretch or manipulate a given segment and it will affect the data displayed in the chart above.

I use chart.js throughout the rest of my projects, so I don't want to switch to High Charts here, but I was wondering if anyone had implemented anything similar to this in Chart.js or if anyone had an idea of how you could build a component that would allow this kind of behavior.

Comment: One more to the issue. Are there any solutions yet?